# JAVA Socket object + text

Tags: java, sockets

Does it possible, to get from client and
`objetObjectInputStream` 
and
`in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`

for example, some client send me tet message, and someone send files. Should I make a new socket server for each?

```
 public class ServerRequests {
Connection con = new Connection();
private Socket socket;

private BufferedReader in;

private BufferedWriter out;

public ServerRequests(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    run();

}

public void run() {

    String word;
    
      try {
          String object;
        ObjectInputStream obIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while ((object = (String) obIn.readObject()) != null){
            
        if (object.contains("F47S")){
            String[] result = object.split(":");
            String fileName = result[1];
            String url = result[2];
            String culture = result[3];
        System.out.println("FileName:" +fileName);
        System.out.println("url:" +url);
          FileOutputStream  outOb = null;
        if(culture.contains("test")) {
           outOb = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        }
              DataInputStream inOb = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              byte[] bytes = new byte[5*1024];
              int count, total=0;
              long lenght = inOb.readLong();
              while ((count = inOb.read(bytes)) > -1) {
                  total+=count;
                  outOb.write(bytes, 0, count);
                  if (total==lenght) break;
              }
              outOb.close();
          }
        
    }
      }catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
      
    try {
        
          
        // while (true) {
        word = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(word);
        if (word != null) {

            String[] result = word.split(":");
            String type = result[0];

            if (type.contains("AUTH")) {
                String login = result[2];
                String pass = result[4];
                String gui = con.checkLogin(pass, login);
                auth(gui);
        
        }

         
          } catch (IOException e) {
          
          }
}


private void auth(String gui) {
    try {
        out.write(gui + "\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
}
private void success(String status) {
    try {
          out.write(status+ "\n");
            out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Create your sockets to send either text (readers/writers) or non-textual data (such as ObjectOutputStream/ ObjectInputStream), but not a mixed picture as you appear to be doing

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  What shell I do, when I need to send and pictures and text, but not in the same time? 
SHell I chage all data to object?